# Can users give an app permission so the app can make the device discoverable whenever it needs to?

Tags: java, android, ios, bluetooth

I'm developing an app that needs to do bluetooth scans at random intervals over an hour period. The app also relies on the device being discoverable during these intervals. Since android have maxed the length of time a device can be discoverable for to 300 seconds I need to find a work around so I can make the device discoverable for 3, 300 second periods over an hour without user interaction. I'm ok with the user having to allow the app to become discoverable on the first scan just not with the other 2.

Any help is massively appreciated here, I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 0):

See the following code:

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

This sets the duration time of the phone to be discoverable for 5 minutes, or 300 seconds. It displays a dialog to get the permission from the user.

Also, if you want to make the phone discoverable all the time, use the following:

```
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);
```

However, know that this is highly discouraged for security purposes.

You can get more information at the following link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth

If you have no idea how to start, I would advise you to do some reading, check examples and / or watch tutorials on YouTube.

Good luck,